# How to compare tuples of different length?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, stdtuple

I would like to write a comparator which compares tuples of different length but have the same "prefix". Consider following case, I have two tuples.

```
auto t1 = std::make_tuple(10, "Test1");
auto t2 = std::make_tuple(10, "Test", 3.14);
```

I would like to apply "less" for t1 < t2, where only two first members of tuple are compared (same type?) and the third one is just omited. Is it possible?

Comment: What stops you from doing that? Show us some efforts :) Hint: think recursion.

Comment: Sounds academical. What if you have tuples A,B and A,C where the A's are the same and B and C  are of different (incomparable) types?

Comment: @SergeyA, actually, I simply dont know how to approach it :)

Comment: @DieterLücking, good question, in this case, I guess compile time error should be issued

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since no one has chimed in, here is the solution. It uses C++14 `std::index_sequence`, so the recursion is hidden in it.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<class... ARGS1, class... ARGS2, std::size_t... Is>
bool tuple_compare_helper(const std::tuple<ARGS1...>& lhs, const std::tuple<ARGS2...>& rhs, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return std::tie(std::get<Is>(lhs)...) < std::tie(std::get<Is>(rhs)...);

}

template<class... ARGS1, class... ARGS2> 
bool tuple_compare(const std::tuple<ARGS1...>& lhs, const std::tuple<ARGS2...>& rhs) {
  const auto min_size = std::min(sizeof...(ARGS1), sizeof...(ARGS2));

  return tuple_compare_helper(lhs, rhs, std::make_index_sequence<min_size>());
}

// test driver
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  auto t1 = std::make_tuple(1, std::string("One"), 2.0);
  auto t2 = std::make_tuple(3, std::string("Two"));


  std::cout << tuple_compare(t2, t1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::make_tuple` will... make a new tuple of copies just to compare corresponding elements, which is not the most efficient approach. consider using `std::tie` for that

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, just what I was thinking :) Will edit and replace.

Comment: Ok, quite interesting technique, however, I dont understand what code is going to be generated when std::get<Is>(lhs)... is called? Could you elaborate please? In any case this is the correct answer

Comment: `std::min`  is `constexpr` nowadays so your expression for `min_size` can be simplified a bit.

Comment: @MSalters, fair enough, didn't know this. Will edit.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, this is called *pack expansion*: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion . Basically, it will be replaced with `(std::get<0>(lhs), std::get<1>(lhs>, ..., std::get<N>(lhs))`, where N is the last index in Is.

Comment: However, if you do not like pack expansion, you can achieve the same functionality by recursively calling `<` on every member of the tuple.

Comment: Ah, I guess I've overlooked the pack expansion in function call, thanks! And sure I like it, compact and elegant, thanks again!

Answer (score -6):

t1 and t2 are of purely different types,so you can't compare them. (tuples are template type; they aren't polymorphic at runtime)
I think the only t-way to do this is a temporary tuple  which takes t2 first and seconds elements to do the comparison