# Compare two tuples but only the first two args

Tags: c++, std, c++17, stdtuple

I have a `std::tuple` e.g.

```
std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t> key{};
std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t> key2{};
const auto [k, p, r] = key;
```

and I want to compare with a second tuple but only the first two args. Something like that:

```
if(std::tie(k, p, std::ignore) < std::tie(key)) { ... }
```

If I do it in the this way, I get the following error:

```
error C2338: cannot compare tuples of different sizes
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT1:**

Both tuple have the same size. I seen how two compare on EQUAlITY with `std::tie()` but it would be nicer I could write:

```
if(std::tie(k, p, std::ignore) == std::tie(key)) { ... }
```

**EDIT2:**

Also what if I want this:

```
if(std::tie(k, std::ignore, p) == std::tie(key)) { ... }
```

Comment: I think this one answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563209/how-to-compare-tuples-of-different-length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare tuples of different length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563209/how-to-compare-tuples-of-different-length)

Comment: No, my tuples has the same size.

Comment: just change the `tuple_compare` and use argument that you would provide instead of using `sizeof ...` looks like it should work

Comment: `std::tie(key)`, `key` is already a tuple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also what if I want this:
>
> `if(std::tie(k, std::ignore, p) == std::tie(key)) { ... }`

So you want compare sub-tuples with some elements of original tuples? Not necessarily the first two elements?

What about a function that, given a tuple object an template variadic index list, return the corresponding sub-tuple?

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
auto getSubTuple (T const & t)
 { return std::tie(std::get<Is>(t)...); }
```

So you can write

```
   std::tuple<std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t> key{0, 1, 2};
   std::tuple<std::uint16_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint32_t> key2{0, 3, 2};
    
   std::cout << (getSubTuple<0u, 2u>(key) == getSubTuple<0u, 2u>(key2)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are comparing a tuple of size 3 (`std::tie(k, p, std::ignore)`) with a tuple of size 1 (`std::tie(key)`, which has the type `std::tuple<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t>>`). You shouldn't call tie on a tuple, because it will create a tuple with a single item in it.

The following code also fail with GCC 8.2.1 because the compiler doesn't know how to handle the `std::ignore` comparison with an `uint32_t`. In this case I would write a specialized compare function for this type (`std::tuple<std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t>>`).

```cpp
#include<tuple>

int main() {
    uint16_t k = 0;
    uint16_t p = 0;
    std::tuple<uint16_t, uint16_t, uint32_t> key{};
    if(std::tie(k, p, std::ignore) < key) {
        // TODO
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're correct an I should have said a custom comparison function (not operator).

Comment: I don't know if I am fond of the compare function. I personally prefer the sub-tuple approach, but your ideea is a valid option that might make sense in certain scenarios. However in the current state your post is barely an answer. You can improve it by showing an implementation of the function.

Comment: Simon Doppler: That was you said that I compare a tuple of different size was an example to solve the problem. The reason why I come here was that I want to compare tuples with the same size but ignore args.